# "In case of cancel"... lation?

Tags: vocabulary

I see this phrase written very often, and in legal documents, which are at least in theory more often correct than the "average" text:

> in case of cancel, ...

It sounds incorrect, and I suppose it is, but is there a context where this phrase is grammatically correct, or more appropriate than *in case of cancellation*?

The only use for *cancel* as noun that I know of is "a mark made on a postage stamp to show that it has been used", which is not the case here (the phrase is being used in a contract clause about cancellation of purchase).

**Edit:** By carefully looking at the examples, they all seem a bit crappy in terms of English quality. Also, some of them seem to alternate between *cancellation* and *cancel* indiscriminately.

http://www.pragueresidences.com/terms.php

http://www.astanapengembak.com/bali-free-and-easy-package.html

http://www.chambre-avec-vue.eu/rentagreement.pdf

http://billetavion.opodo.fr/opodo/flights/fareNotes?pnr=24X57E&opodoConfNum=0014179106&locale=fr_FR_109

http://www.villa-pavlina.cz/EN/cenik.htm

http://www.larrakoetxea.com/precios_en.html

http://www.hostels.com/es/albergues/rio-de-janeiro/best-rio-hostel/35087

http://www.lazycow.com/nav/terms

**Edit 2:** I agree, my question is not very useful. If it should be kept in the hope that Google will help some of those poor translators to avoid the same mistake, or if it should be erased, I'm not sure. Either way is fine for me, but I do not know how to actually improve the question. I'll delete it if recommended to.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?  A 'legal notice' may just be something cooked up by a junior manager to try and frighten competitors.

Comment: I'm going to say it's "unclear what OP is asking". I'm not a lawyer, so I admit I don't spent my days perusing legal texts. But if *in case of cancel* really did turn up in such contexts I'd expect to find a reasonable number in Google Books. But there are actually only 13 in total, and most of them are OCR errors where ***-lation*** appears as the next "word". On the other hand, there are apparently 60,000 instances of *in case of **cancellation***. The real question seems to be "Why does OP see this phrase written very often"?

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly considered too many bad quality sources, instead of trying to search for books... thanks for the tip, I'll consider it in the future.

Comment: "legal documents, which are at least in theory more often correct than the "average" text" - I would argue with this assumption of yours. Legal texts often have their own accepted vocabulary, style and even grammatical idiosyncracies which would be considered incorrect out of their specific scope.

Comment: This question boils down to "grammatical errors appear in poorly written documents. Discuss."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at all the references you've mentioned, and searched them all for the word "cancel".

I agree that they all (except one) contain variations on the wording "In case of cancel".  It's clear to me that they all mean "In case of cancellation" or "In case of [you] cancelling".

In the http://www.lazycow.com/nav/terms document, all instances of "cancel" seem to be using it correctly as a verb.

I have some experience of reading, writing and reviewing legal documents, and I would not expect such documents to have such errors. On the other hand, a number of them seem to have been written by people whose native language is not English. Although I haven't looked at them in sufficient detail to check this, I note that they all relate to accommodation and I wonder whether there has been some copying or some common source for the documents.

As regards your underlying question, no, (as far as I am aware) that phrase is not grammatically correct, and I don't recall ever seeing it used in that fashion. However, [*one* dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cancel) (I only checked two!) does give *cancel* as a noun, with the definition "a less common word for *cancellation*".

As regards your statement

> The only use for cancel as noun that I know of is "a mark made on a postage stamp to show that it has been used".

I would again say that even there the normal word is "cancellation".

Finally (just 'in case of relevance'), I am writing from a UK perspective.

Comment: I agree that stamps have cancellations, not cancels.

Answer (score 2):

The word *cancel* as a noun has appeared in the Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series since the Seventh Edition (1963). The most recent edition, the Eleventh (2003), provides this definition:

> **cancel** *n* (1806) **1:** CANCELLATION **2a:** a deleted part or passage **b**(1): a leaf containing matter to be deleted (2): a new leaf or slip substituted for matter already printed

Clearly the poster's question is about the legitimacy of using *cancel* to mean *cancellation*, and just as clearly Merriam-Webster's has been reporting that definition for the past 50 years, though I doubt that use of the word in that sense is widespread or generally admired.

Recasting verbs as nouns without bothering to alter their endings is by no means uncommon. For example, in recent years, you may have noticed the emergence of "the reveal" for "the revealing" (or "the revelation" or "the unveiling"), and "a fresh install" for "a fresh installation" (of a computer operating system).

Ultimately, real-world use or abandonment, not fiat, will determine the fate of *cancel* as an alternative to *cancellation*.